# Escaping characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=XXXXXXX');
    query.setQuery('SELECT B, C, D, E, F, G, H where upper(B) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or upper(D) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or upper(E) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") or upper(F) like upper("%<?php echo $search; ?>%") order by G DESC label G "Data"');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();

    var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat(
        '<a href="{6}" target="_blank" onclick="var that=this;_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\',\'Download archivio materiali\',\'{2}\',this.href]);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">{2}</a>');
    // Apply formatter and set the formatted value of the first column.
    formatter.format(data, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([2, 0, 1, 4, 5]); // Create a view with the first column only.

    visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
    visualization.draw(view, {
        legend: 'bottom',
        allowHtml: true
    });

}
```

This is the smaller snippet interested by this question:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('<a href="{6}" target="_blank" onclick="var that=this;_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\',\'Download archivio materiali\',\'{2}\',this.href]);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">{2}</a>');
```

It does work fine (it outputs a legit anchor with the correct data), except when in the title of the document (output by the variable `{2}`) is present a character like a double quote ("). The anchor syntax would get screwed:

[image]

Do I need to escape/replace the double quotes using a function like replace? How can I do that?

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/xyqF7/15/)**

Comment: Can you provide a running example with JavaScript libraries included on https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Hi Quasimodo, this is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/multiformeingegno/xyqF7/15/

Comment: See the jsfiddle in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! It was much more complicated than I thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try on the replacement for {2} something like:

```
var str = 'say: "blabla"';
str = str.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
console.log(str);
```

I've updated your [fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/Esistwieesist/dmab3933/) and have inserted:

```
// add a column with manipulated data
  var targetColIdx = data.getNumberOfColumns();          // will be the index of added column
  data.addColumn('string');
  var sourceColIdx = 2;                                  // get data from col 2
  var rowCount = data.getNumberOfRows();                 // save for loop condition
  var manipulated = "";
  for(var rowIndex=0; rowIndex<rowCount; rowIndex++)
  { manipulated = data.getValue(rowIndex, sourceColIdx); // get original
    manipulated = encodeURIComponent(manipulated);       // do some manipulation
    data.setCell(rowIndex, targetColIdx, manipulated);   // store in new column
  }

// modificated format: only use uri-encoded column in onclick attribute
  var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat(
    '<a href="{6}" target="_blank" onclick="var that=this;_gaq.push([\'_trackEvent\',\'Download archivio materiali\',\'{'+targetColIdx+'}\',this.href]);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},200);return false;">{2}</a>');
```

I've not further investigated what will happen to the string in the click event handler. Maybe you will need another encoding or escaping as in the RegExp example above. You can adapt the line `manipulated = encodeURIComponent(manipulated);` to your needs.

Comment: Can I do `console.log({2}.replace(/"/g, '\\"'));` ?

Comment: I don't know the Google API. I think the variable {2} is some field in `data` fetched from `response.getDataTable()`. `console.log` is just a debug output. You can open the console in Firefox with ctrl+shift+k.

Comment: I guess `data[1]` (because index based on 0) could be the replacement {2}. Try a `console.log(data)`, open console, click on the output and examine the data structure.

Comment: I tried with `var str = data[1]; console.log(str.replace(/"/g, '\\"'));` but I got `UNDEFINED`. If I put `console.log(data)` I get A LOT of data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pv0jho61ucc426j/Screenshot%202016-03-29%2018.19.13.png?dl=0

Comment: Maybe `data.getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)` and `data.setValue(rowIndex, columnIndex, value)` could help. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods . I needed a running live example to find out more. Can you setup one on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Ok, I'll setup one today

Comment: I've added the JSFiddle link as a comment to the question